# I need a tool that could help verify replication timing of GPO

Tags: group-policy

I have created a domain level GPO that causes the message "Logon is prohibited to unauthorized personnel" to be presented to users when logging on.

I need to modify the GPO such that the domain controller group policy replication is set to occur every 15 minutes and computer group policy replication to occur once every 3 hours.

Could someone tell me a tool I need that could help me verify replication timing? Also it would be nice if someone could show me how to set it up as well.

Comment: When you say "replication," do you mean of objects between domain controllers (AD Replication) or policy settings between clients and the domain (GP Updates)? They are two separate things with two separate answers.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.Are you inquiring about policy processing and refresh intervals (i.e. how often the policies applicable to a user/computer are read and processed in the background)? Or literally about replicating a change done to a GPO to other DCs?

Comment: I think it may be that.

Comment: @Grace Which "that?"

Comment: I believe grace wants both. To verify that it's being replicated every 15 minutes to a BDC and that the group polices are updating on the clients every 3 hours.

Comment: If we're going by beliefs, I believe that this is a homework question. That's just me, though.

Answer (score 2):

AD (NTDS) replication is controlled within the AD Sites and Services management console (dssite.msc). You can modify the site links and NTDS settings within there.

For modifying how often clients refresh their policy, you should use Group Policy. Navigate to Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > System > Group Policy, and change the Group Policy Refresh Interval settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tool [`repadmin`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770963%28WS.10%29.aspx) to inspect connections between AD domain controllers:

> You can use Repadmin.exe to view the replication topology, as seen from the perspective of each domain controller. In addition, you can use Repadmin.exe to manually create the replication topology, to force replication events between domain controllers, and to view both the replication metadata and up-to-dateness vectors (UTDVECs). You can also use Repadmin.exe to monitor the relative health of an Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) forest.

For investigating a specific client, you can use [`gpresult`](http://www.tech-faq.com/troubleshooting-group-policy.html) to learn about:

> - When Group Policy was last applied
> - The domain controller which applied Group Policy
> - Information on all GPOs that are applied, and details for these
> - Information on the Registry settings that are applied, and details for these
> - Scripts
> - Software management information and details on published and assigned applications
> - Disk quota information
> - Internet Protocol (IP) security settings
> - Redirected folder information, and details on these.